# How to get list of KBs via QnA maker API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to build a POC using QnA maker API, that can be integrated into my application.How can I get the list of KB's via API? I have voted for the this [feature](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/578689-qna-maker-api/suggestions/19675621-consider-a-get-method-to-list-your-kb-ids). Is this done or can be used now.?

Answer (score 0):

It exists in the new QnAMaker API v4.0, and it's there: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_getknowledgebasesforuser

But you will need an `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header where you place your subscription key, and I can't find a way to have this key.

For previous versions of the API, the key was:

> Subscription key which provides access to this API. Found in your QnAMaker Service accounts.

For this v4:

> Subscription key which provides access to this API. Found in your
>   Cognitive Services accounts.

I checked, it's not the keys located on `https://qnamaker.ai/UserSettings` and in my Azure portal, under `AI + Cognitive Services`, there is no QnA product like for LUIS API or other APIs.

Probably this v4 API is still not "official", we have to wait a bit.

*EDIT April 23rd: QnAMaker API v4.0 is not more listed on Cognitive Services API services list...*
*EDIT May 3rd: QnAMaker API v4.0 is back on the list!*